# Missing my earlier posts in activity on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, support

Once I have asked a question on Stack Overflow, but it is no longer there in any of my activity. Maybe I have edited that question, but it is also not showing throughout my entire history activity. Why is it gone?

Comment: Recently deleted post is usually good place to find such stuff (link can be found on profile tab for questions/answers below all other links)

Answer (score 2):

Since you have the [peer pressure badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/38/peer-pressure?userid=2781244), you likely deleted it, presumably on or about September 11th 2014. (Unless that was an answer deletion).

Given that it's been deleted more than a year ago you'll have to ask a moderator to find it if you want it back again as it's too old to appear in your recent deleted posts list.

Comment: Users can now search with `deleted:1` and see all of their deleted content.

Comment: @NathanOliver are you sure?  Doesn't work for me on meta or the main site.  But does work on MSE.  Probably a 20K privilege.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Ah dang.  It is a 10K priv: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145060/enable-searching-with-deleted1-for-10k-users